# How to create a compilation unit from an AST

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am writing a solution which requires an AST to be generated and then this AST should be parsed in order to generate a valid compilation unit with semantics available.

1. The AST is generated by means of `SyntaxFactory` class.
2. Then I will need to get a `Compilation` somehow.
3. Then I will get a reference to `SemanticModel` from the compilation unit.

#### Creating the AST

The code I run for generating the AST is something like:

```
var classNode = SyntaxFactory.ClassDeclaration("MyCLass");
classNode = classNode.AddMembers(
  SyntaxFactory.MethodDeclaration(SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName("string"), "DoIt")
    .WithBody(...));
...
```

#### Missing parts

The first part is ok as you can see. I can get my AST. But now I need to convert it into code? **How to invoke the compiler on the AST?**:

```
              Compiler                Compilation.GetSemanticModel(AST)
              |                       |
     +-----+  v  +-----------------+  v  +---------------+
+----> AST +-----> CompilationUnit +-----> SemanticModel |
  ^  +-----+     +-----------------+     +---------------+
  |              ^                 ^
  |              |-----------------|
  Factories              ???
```

Note that the part relative to getting the `SemanticModel` is covered as I simly need to use the `Compilation` object and call `GetSemanticModel` on that by passing the `CSharpSyntaxTree`.

If you are wondering why this, it is because of a testing tool I am writing. Regardless of the use, **this scenario should be possible**. How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create `Compilation` in Roslyn, you need a valid syntax tree, to get a valid syntax tree you can just parse text like:

```
var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"using System;
              namespace HelloWorld
              {
                public class MyType{public void MyMethod(){} public void MySecondMethod(){}}
              }"));
```

Or you can use `SyntaxFactory` (or `SyntaxGenerator`) like you wrote. (just add `usings` and `namespace` unless you writing a `CSharpScript`, its required, You can also check [RoslynQuoter](https://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/) to get a valid `SyntaxTree`)

When you have a valid `SyntaxTree` you can write this to get a `Compilation` and `SemanticModel`

```
 var options = new CSharpCompilationOptions(kind);
 var root = (CompilationUnitSyntax)tree.GetRoot();
 var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("HelloWorld", options: options).
                   AddReferences(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location)).
                   AddSyntaxTrees(tree);
 var model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);
```